# How to store image in SqlCe Database for windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

not sure how to do this since there is no ado.net in Windows Phone. Would appreciate if you can show me some code and sample.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use image data type, see this sample: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-save-and-retrieve-images-using.html

Comment: Will get back here after trying the method.

Comment: Would like to know is there any data limit on :1) Varbinary, binary 2) image in sqlCe Database. For example : limit for varbinary 8000kb. so what about image datatype? Convert picture into byte[] or stream for image dataType ? Thanks

Comment: Binary and varbinary max size is 8000 bytes, for image 2 GB

Comment: Thank.Windows phone has at least 5MegaPixel cam, a high resolution photo will easily exceed 3MegaByte or more. Will try to rework the Image before storing. I dont know if there is a limit of SqlCe Database size.

Comment: Max db size on Windows Phone is 512 MB

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to approaches:

1- If your images are not going to be very large, then you can store Base64 string of image data as a string field in database.

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData); // and store this to database
var imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(imageDataString); // read image data from database
```

2- otherwise you can assign your image (or database record) a unique GUID and store your image in IsolatedStorageFile.

```
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf)))
    {
        writer.Write(imageData);
    }
}
```

will add code in a minute

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. I will try option (1). However, base64 will not support by IE-browser when I use the Image Control for the Base64 Data. So, I look for Varbinary in SqlCe To store image. how this will be done?

Comment: You didn't mention u want to use it in browser control. For showing it on a silverlight Image control, that should work. I personally choose option (2) it's more reliable.

Comment: Option2 should work on ISO. HOwever, I need to store image inside SqlCe DB. Good idea to store image as base64 in SqlCeDb. However, I like to store it as stream. Thank